# How to write key + values to a JSON file with Node.js and Socket.io

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, socket.io

I am working on a scoreboard with Socket.io and Node.js . Now I would like to save the scores of the participants into a JSON file.

This is what I tried to do:

```
socket.on('part score', function(name, score){
    let jdata = fs.readFileSync('participants.json');
    let json = JSON.parse(jdata);
console.log(name, score);
//outputs: foo 10

    fs.writeFile('participants.json', JSON.stringify(json.jury1.push({name: score}, null, 2)), function(){
        console.log("name added: "+name+" value added: "+score);
    }); 
});
```

How my JSON file looks like:

```
{"jury1": []}
```

When I executed to code above my JSON files turns into "3" when the score is 10. Also everything in my JSON file is gone after execution.

How do I properly add the key+value into my Jury1?
Thanks already!
ps: name and score gets send through the client sided script

Answer (score 0):

Jury1 is an array?

I think that you should parse all the data that you want so instead of doing:

`JSON.stringify(json.jury1.push({name: score}, null, 2)`

try something like:

`jury1 with the score you need
var data = JSON.stringify(jury1)`

Comment: as @aega said `jury1` must be an object and not a json string

Comment: But i want to put objects+value into Jury1

Comment: I assume you have jury1 somewhere in your code, so put all data you need on them and serialize it to json only once

Comment: I've added this and it works now!
`json.jury1.push(`${name}:${score}`);
  fs.writeFile('participants.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 2), function(){
   console.log("name added: "+name+" value added: "+score);
  }); `

Comment: doesn't make any sense at all. is this script in your js file or any template file ?

Answer (score 0):

You already have a json file. Why are you doing a JSON.parse again ? I suspect that is the issue. can you try to print the content of json.jury1 to confirm the same ?

Also, check the result from fs.writeFile() if there is any err

```
fs.writeFile('participants.json', JSON.stringify(json.jury1.push({name: score}, null, 2)), function(err){
    console.log(err, "name added: "+name+" value added: "+score);
});
```

Comment: I thought you had to parse the JSON file first and then Stringify it again?

Comment: only if your initial file contents are string '{"jury1": []}' instead of json {"jury1": []}